# Retrieve Facebook users that like a URL / web page via Open Graph

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql, facebook-opengraph

Is there a way to retrieve the list of Facebook users that have clicked the like button on an external website?

- E.g. there is a domain *example.com* which has been confirmed via [Facebook Insights](http://www.facebook.com/insights/) to belong to *fbUser1* ([using OG meta tags](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/#admin)).
- Somewhere on *example.com* there is a page with multiple XFBL like buttons, each one pointing to a further specific URL on *example.com*, e.g. *example.com/xyz*, *example.com/abc* etc.

**What I'd like to get is the list of users that liked *example.com/xyz* and of those who liked *example.com/abc*.**

My intuitive approach would be to look at ***graph.facebook.com/123456789/likes*** (where the number is the ID of the domain taken from FB insights), but this always returns an empty dataset:

```js
{
   "data": [

   ]
}
```

I've also tried getting an OAuth access token from https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?type=client_cred&client_id=APPID&client_secret=APPSECRET (where *APPID* and *APPSECRET* are taken from a FB application that is marked as owning the domain using OG meta tags), but that makes no difference.

I'd also be interested in a non-OpenGraph (i.e. JS SDK, FQL etc.) solution.

**EDIT**: Using the following code (according to [WideBlade](https://stackoverflow.com/users/491214/wideblade)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4876422/retrieve-facebook-users-that-like-a-url-web-page-via-open-graph/4876976#4876976) below) still gives me an empty list of likes (the second query never returns):

```js
var objectsQuery = "select id from object_url where url in ('http://example.com/xyz', 'http://example.com/abc', 'http://example.com/123')";
var likesQuery = "select object_id from like where object_id = {0}";

FB.Data.query(objectsQuery).wait(function (objectRows) {
    console.log(objectRows);

    FB.Array.forEach(objectRows, function (objectRow) {
        FB.Data.query(likesQuery, objectRow.object_id).wait(function (likeRows) {
            console.log(likeRows);
        })
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This cannot be done. Facebook does not allow you to query for specific user ID's of people who have liked a certain page. This is because of privacy concerns.

See the disclaimer on this page https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/like/

Answer (score 5):

FQL Should do the trick.

`$facebook->api_client->fql_query('SELECT user_id FROM like WHERE object_id="OBJECTID"');`

[Here is the link.](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/like/)

[Some general info about FQL.](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/)

FQL is initiated using the JavaScript SDK, [in this way.](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/fb.data.query/)

If you can post some sample code-I can try and give some more specific help.

A note should be made-once you've got the user ID's, you can just query the names and get them in a list.

**EDIT:** To get the URL of an object you should [query this table using fql](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/object_url/).

Comment: Lovely, thanks.
How do I get an OBJECTID for an external url like example.com/xyz?

Comment: Thanks again, accepted as obviously correct.
However using JS SDK and FQL the list of likes is still empty.
See edit for sample.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't think this is a JS problem.

The code works fine, and the results are the same as when querying the OpenGraph or even the old REST API.

The question is really: is there a way to retrieve the specific users who like an external url?