# Retrieve Facebook users who like a URL/web page

Tags: facebook, facebook-fql, facebook-like, facebook-javascript-sdk

How can I retrieve the list of Facebook users that have clicked the like button on an external site?

Say I have a like button:

```
<fb:like href="http://example.com/xyz"></fb:like>
```

I'd like a list of FB user IDs of people who have liked it.

I've tried OpenGraph:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/OBJECTID/likes/
```

(where OBJECTID is the id of the like example.com/xyz)

and FQL

```
select user_id from like where object_id in (
    select id from object_url where url = 'http://example.com/xyz'))
```

but both return empty results.

I can see from other calls that the likes are counted alright, but I can't get the actual users.

Anyone know what permissions etc. I'd need to retrieve these?

---

Also see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4876422/retrieve-facebook-users-that-like-a-url-web-page-via-open-graph) for sample code.

Comment: probably more appropriate to webapps.SE

Comment: I don't think so. This is a Facebook API development question, not a Facebook usage question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simple answer is '**Its not possible to get individual user ids who liked a page**'.

```
https://graph.facebook.com/cocacola/likes?access_token='xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
```

will surely return the data about the likes from the user/page but not the list of users who liked the specific object(in this case coca-cola). But make sure you send a proper access_token with proper permissions.

The [FQL like](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/like/) is used to get the likes of any objects like video, note, link, photo, or album. To get liked users count of a page please use either [link_stat](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/link_stat/) or [page](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/page/) from FQL.

the sample query will be like

```
SELECT url, normalized_url, share_count, like_count, comment_count, total_count,
commentsbox_count, comments_fbid, click_count FROM link_stat WHERE url="facebook.com"

SELECT name, fan_count FROM page WHERE page_id = 19292868552
```

For more clear answers on this, please read the answer by Jonathan Dean in [How to list facebook users who like a page or interest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3546320/how-to-list-facebook-users-who-like-a-page-or-interest)

or ifaour answer in [Querying Users who 'like' my Facebook Page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5183251/querying-users-who-like-my-facebook-page)