# Fan page shows photos in lower quality to non-fans

Tags: facebook-like, photo, fan-page

I was wondering if it is possible to realize the next scenario:
On a photography fan page, to show photo albums to all visitors but to have the photos within the albums shown in a small format to all non-fan visitors. Once the visitors LIKE the page, show the photos in normal size.

Thanks in advance for your advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems awfully similar to this question: [Retrieve Facebook users that like a URL / web page via Open Graph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4876422/retrieve-facebook-users-that-like-a-url-web-page-via-open-graph) It shows it's not possible to retrieve the likes of a page.

Maybe you can create a FB app which shows the photo's and, based on whether they have liked your page, the app shows the high res photo. It is possible to embed your site in a FB app, you could use this approach to show the high res or low res version of your site.